# SapUi5 Table Multiple Filter

Tags: sapui5

I'm developing a sap ui5 application using sap.ui.table.Table.

I need to apply a filter based on multiple strings.  For example, if the user input is an array like:

```
["Stack", "Overflow"]
```

I need:

1. Filter all table fields by `"Stack"`;
2. Filter the result of point `1` by `"Overflow"`;

the result will be all rows that have `"Stack"` and `"Overflow"`, no matter the field.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter with "OR" And "AND" Conditions on Multiple Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433200/filter-with-or-and-and-conditions-on-multiple-fields)

Answer (score 1):

As per the [sap.ui.model.Filter documentation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Filter.html), you can create a filter either based on a filter info object, or from an array of previously created filters. This allows us to do the following:

- Create a filter for the first value (eg "Stack")
- Create a filter for the second value (eg "Overflow")
- Create a filter which contains both of these values, and use it to filter the table.

Let's have a look at some code.

```
// We will only display rows where ProductName contains 
// "Stack" AND CustomerName equals "Overflow"

var oFilterForProductName,
    oFilterForCustomerName,
    aArrayWhichContainsBothPreviousFilters = [],
    oFilterToSetOnTheTable;

var sValueToFilterTheProductNameOn = "Stack",
    sValueToFilterTheCustomerNameOn = "Overflow";

var sKeyForProductNameInTheTableModel = "ProductName",
    sKeyForCustomerNameInTheTableModel = "CustomerName";

var oTableToFilter = this.byId("myTableId");

// Step 1: create two filters
oFilterForProductName = new sap.ui.model.Filter(
    sKeyForProductNameInTheTableModel, 
    sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, 
    sValueToFilterTheProductNameOn);
oFilterForCustomerName = new sap.ui.model.Filter(
    sKeyForCustomerNameInTheTableModel, 
    sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, 
    sValueToFilterTheCustomerNameOn);

// Step 2: add these two filters to an array
aArrayWhichContainsBothPreviousFilters.push(oFilterForProductName);
aArrayWhichContainsBothPreviousFilters.push(oFilterForCustomerName);

// Step 3: create a filter based on the array of filters
oFilterToSetOnTheTable = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
    filters: aArrayWhichContainsBothPreviousFilters,
    and: true
});

oTableToFilter.getBinding("items").filter(oFilterToSetOnTheTable , sap.ui.model.FilterType.Application);
```

Hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions.

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Please pass that array in for loop and pass filters like,

```
var tableId = this.byId("oTable");
for(var i=0;i < array.length ; i++)
{
    oTable.getBinding().filter(new sap.ui.model.Filter("", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.Contains, array[0]));

}
```

it may be helpful for you.